# React.js - Redux Hooks Invalid Hook Call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to use `useDispatch` inside my component's render function.

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
```

I have a input that tries to useDispatch on `onChange`

```
onChange={() => useDispatch()(update("test"))}
```

When onChange is fired, I get this error:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import {
    useDispatch
} from 'react-redux';
import {
    update
} from '../store/actions';
class Something extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<input onChange={() => useDispatch()(update("test"))}/>)
    }
}

export default Something;
```

Comment: `useDispatch` is the custom hook you built or from any other lib?

Comment: @ArupRakshit - From the [tag:redux] tag, presumably [this one](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch).

Comment: From react-redux.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks. I wish I could use this awesome React in my day job.. :( Anyway good to know.. I am looking at it now.

Comment: `Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're using it in `render` in a class component. You can't use hooks in class components. That's why the error message says

> Invalid hook call. **Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.**

*(my emphasis)*. Class components aren't function components. (That's a bit easy to miss, would be good if the list of possible causes mentioned class components specifically.)

So you'd want to make it a function component:

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import {
    useDispatch
} from 'react-redux';
import {
    update
} from '../store/actions';
function Something() {                                              // ***
    return <input onChange={() => useDispatch()(update("test"))}/>; // ***
}                                                                   // ***

export default Something;
```

Also note the warning in [the documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch) that the above will cause unnecessary rendering and that you should use `useCallback`:

```
import React, {
    Component,
    useCallback
} from 'react';
import {
    useDispatch
} from 'react-redux';
import {
    update
} from '../store/actions';
function Something() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();            // ***
    const handleChange = useCallback(          // ***
        () => dispatch(update("test")),        // ***
        [dispatch]                             // ***
    );                                         // ***
    return <input onChange={handleChange}/>;   // ***
}

export default Something;
```

Comment: Yeah.. That's it. I somehow smell that there is something relevant which the OP didn't show us. So I asked the OP to show more code, and that in turn open the source of error. :)

Comment: How will i then be able to use state in a simple function?

Comment: @Hobey823 - See [the hooks documentation on using state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are not using it correctly, try this:

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch()

...
onChange={() => dispatch(update("test"))}
```

See [documentation of useDispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch), there is example of its usage.

Comment: Does not work.
```31 | 
  32 | render() {
> 33 |   const dispatch = useDispatch();
     | ^  34 |   return (```

Comment: @Hobey823 Show more code, probably that will help us. :)

Comment: This code does what the OP"s code does. The only difference is that you've separated it into its separate parts. The OP's code calls `useDispatch` and then immediately calls the function it returns. Your code just puts it in `dispatch` first, then calls it. (Both yours and the OP's ignore the documentation's note that you probably want `useCallback` in there to avoid unnecessary rendering...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, (but only for the useDispatch hook, as it is provides I suppose just a function without any side effects), but OP says, that he has a problem with React warnings. They are there because his code is breaking the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html EDIT: in time of my answer, we didn't know that OP uses hooks in the class component instead of the functional stateless.